# How to access a struct in a serde serializer

Tags: rust, serde

I've built a Serde serializer that basically transforms an in-memory data structure from standard Rust types into a custom target type `enum Entry`.

My `Serializer` basically just calls `Entry::try_from(value)` in the `serialize_[type]()` functions, like this:

```
    fn serialize_u16(self, v: u16) -> Result<Self::Ok, Self::Error> {
        if let Ok(entry) = Entry::try_from(v) {
            return Ok(entry);
        }
        Err(SerializationError::ExpectedInteger)
    }
```

This works pretty well for all basic types (`String`, `i16`, `u64`, …) and I've also built the logic to create `Entry::Dictionary` from a `HashMap` and `Entry::Array` from `Vec`.

What I can't figure out is how to do this for `struct`s, that I also want to convert.

I know that I have to implement `serde::ser::SerializeStruct` for my `Serializer`. There I get the struct's fields, but have no clue which type of struct I get and also the fields don't have a specific type, so I don't seem to be able to construct the needed `Entry` here.

Is there any way to access the struct? Can I implement specific variants of `serde::ser::SerializeStruct` for the different struct types I want to handle? Can I somehow get the information about the struct type and its field type, so I can construct the needed `Entry`?

Comment: Usually you wouldn't implement `SerializeStruct` for `Entry` but for a helper struct which you construct in `Serializer::serialize_struct` which receives the name of the struct and number of fields, then you call `serialize_field` on it with each name and value of the fields, finally you call `end()` on it and it returns the constructed `Entry`

Comment: @cafce25 I have implemented `SerializeStruct` on a helper struct `EntrySerializer`. My problem is, that I need to know which type of struct I receive in `serialize_struct` and also the type of the fields there, so I can construct a new `Entry` based on that information.

Comment: For serialization the interface provided by `serde` doesn't provide type information besides the structs name (or what string the `Serialize` implementor gives you) or the fields types (again except for their name).

Comment: What `Entry` do you want to build from structs? We need to see the definition of `Entry`. Maybe you just want to create maps for structs?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman `Entry` is an enum consisting of various tuple variants holding structs (`enum Entry { Boolean(BooleanEntry), Point(PointEntry), UnicodeString(UnicodeStringEntry) }`. `BooleanEntry` and `PointEntry` are structs. The whole construct encapsulates an API called via FFI. And no, I don't want to create maps for structs.

Comment: So maybe you can use the struct names to map, or determine via the fields. But I have the feeling that this serialization is the wrong approach.